# Flutter: Maintain multi-dimensional List data type with JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dart, arraylist

I wish to load JSON data of the type of a 2-dimensional array of doubles.
If I attempt to do that via `json.encode` the type is lost.

So, the following fails:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
main() {
  var x = [[0.0,0.0]];
  print(x.runtimeType);               // List<List<double>>
  x = json.decode( json.encode (x) ); // this line fails
}
```

With the error message:

> type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<double>>'

**How can I maintain the type of `List<List<double>>` when loading in JSON data?**

---

I've tried the following:

`x = json.decode( json.encode (x) ) as List<List<double>>;`

> type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<List<double>>' in type cast

`x = List<List<double>>.from(json.decode( json.encode (x) ));`

> type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>'

Comment: Try by declaring and initializing var x at the same time.

Comment: `json.decode` returns a `dynamic` value. There isn't really a good way to do a deep cast, as in casting to a type with generics, [see this issue for more info](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1574). That said, you can do the following in this case `x = [for (var list in json.decode(json.encode(x))) [...list]];`.

Answer (score 1):

While my original post was for a 2D array, my actual problem was with a 4D array.

I ended up with making a custom class to process these :

```dart
class JsonArrayConversion {

  static List<double> convertJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json.map((e) => e as double).toList();  
  }

  static List<List<double>> convertJson2(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json.map((e) {
      if (e is List<dynamic>) {
        return convertJson(e);
      } else {
        return [] as List<double>;
      }    
    }).toList();
  }

  static List<List<List<double>>> convertJson3(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json.map((e) {
      if (e is List<dynamic>) {
        return convertJson2(e);
      } else {
        return [] as List<List<double>>;
      }    
    }).toList();
  }

  static List<List<List<List<double>>>> convertJson4(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json.map((e) {
      if (e is List<dynamic>) {
        return convertJson3(e);
      } else {
        return [] as List<List<List<double>>>;
      }    
    }).toList();
  }

}
```

And for the example in the original post, the solution becomes:

`x = JsonArrayConversion.convertJson2( json.decode( json.encode (x) ) );`

Clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class NumbersList {
    NumbersList({
        required this.numbers,
    });

    List<List<double>>? numbers;

    factory NumbersList.fromJson(String str) => NumbersList.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory NumbersList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NumbersList(
        numbers: json["numbers"] == null ? null : List<List<double>>.from(json["numbers"].map((x) => List<double>.from(x.map((x) => x.toDouble())))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "numbers": numbers == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(numbers!.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x)))),
    };
}
```

Use:

var jsonString = '{"numbers": [[1.0, 1, 2],[2.5, 5, 6]]}';
final numbersList = NumbersList.fromJson(jsonString);
print(numbersList.toJson());

Or simply:

```
 var str = "[[1.0, 1, 2],[2.5, 5, 6]]";
 var numbers = json.decode(str);
 var n = List<List<double>>.from(numbers.map((x) => List<double>.from(x.map((x) => x.toDouble()))))
```